# Can't set msnodesql to work

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, node-sqlserver

Ok, i've tryed everything here. I did installed msnodesql from

-https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver

and

-http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29995

following every line of instruction on installation. build with node-gyp... everything.

Then when I do something like:

```
var conn_str = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server={(local)\\SQLEXPRESS};Database={DBName};Trusted_Connection={Yes};";
var stmt = sqlserver.query(conn_str, "SELECT * from av.CLIENT");
stmt.on('meta', function (meta) { console.log("We've received the metadata"); });
stmt.on('row', function (idx) { console.log("We've started receiving a row"); });
stmt.on('column', function (idx, data, more) { console.log(idx + ":" + data); });
stmt.on('done', function () { console.log("All done!"); });
stmt.on('error', function (err) { console.log("We had an error :-( " + err); });
```

it throws me an error on node console:

**[Error: [msnodesql] Invalid  passed to function query. Type should be .]**

What drives me crazy is that it should be something like:

**[Error: [msnodesql] Invalid --SOMETHING-- passed to function query. Type should be --SOMETHING_ELSE--.]**

right?

It doesn't even pass through the **stmt.on('error',** line

I've repeated the installation steps over and over, thinking that maybe there was an error in the building process, but nothing.!

I'm using Windows 8 x64 and node v-0.10 (I wonder if that driver is ment to be use ONLY with node v.0.8 <

I need help. pls.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used node-sqlserver, but I have used [tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) and it worked well.  Give that a try, maybe you'll have better luck?

Comment: I can respect that.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I just found out why it gives errors like Error: [msnodesql] Invalid passed to function query. Type should be .] .

If you happen to have a prototype over the Array object, it will throw this kind of errors. For example, I have a prototype function over the Array class called "indexOfObject".....

To be more specific, there's a file in **msnodesql > lib > sql.js** , in it there's a function called validateParameters.

In there, I changed this:

```
if ( typeof parameters[p].value != parameters[p].type )
```

for this:

```
if ( typeof parameters[p].value != parameters[p].type && parameters[p].name )
```

it may not be overthinked as a solution to all my problems, but at least everything works fine from there on.!